# how to set directly nested keypath in Restkit?

Tags: swift, restkit, restkit-0.20

hi i need to set directly nested keypath in RKResponseDescriptor like "Data.User" but not getting Value my json like below

```
{
 "Data":{
       "User":{
            "name": aaa,
            "mobile": 123456789
        }
 "ResultType":1
 }
}
```

i need directly entity map to User Without data is it possible

EDIT:

my calling code is

```
 let userMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "User", inManagedObjectStore: rkomUser.managedObjectStore)

userMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([
    "Name"                    : "name",
    "Mobile"                  : "mobile"
    ])


let responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(

    mapping: userMapping,

    method: RKRequestMethod.POST,
    pathPattern: nil,

    keyPath: "Data.User",
    statusCodes: NSIndexSet(index: 201)
)
```

Comment: Ok, so what did you try (show code) and what went wrong (also show destination object definition)

Comment: let responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(
        
        mapping: comObject.rtem,
        
        method: requestMethod,
        pathPattern: nil,
        
        keyPath: "Data.User",
        statusCodes: NSIndexSet(index: 201)
    )

Comment: Please edit your question, don't add code in comments, it's unreadable, that code is also only 25% of the info required

Comment: hi @Wain added code in my edit check and tell me

Comment: Just looks like the capitalisation of keys in your mapping doesn't match the JSON...

Comment: i changed to smal in keypath not succedd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96629/discussion-between-sabeer-and-wain).